# National Incident-Based Reporting System (NIBRS) Data?

Tags: data-request

I've read about the National Incident-Based Reporting (NIBRS) data at the [Bureau of Justice Statistics](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=dcdetail&iid=301) site. But I'm not able to actually *find* the data available for use/analysis anywhere.

Does anyone know where this data might be available?

Comment: http://www.asdfree.com/2014/11/analyze-national-incident-based.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the public-use version of the dataset through ICPSR at [this](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/series/128) page. Make sure to register an account through ICPSR. If you don't have an account, then I highly recommend making one. ICPSR is an awesome repository of social science data.